# Page category filter in admin dashboard

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, pages, dashboard

I created page category by this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323582/wordpress-how-to-add-categories-and-tags-on-pages)  ( or custom taxonomy with the help of ACF Extended Plugin). It works. Now I can add pages into category. My problem is that, I can not filter pages by category in admin dashboard. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show on the image is the post status, not a taxonomy.

But a filter already exists to do what you want. Go where you wrote your categories and on the right must be numbers. It's  the number of post_type in each category. Click that number and you'll see
the pages for the clicked category.

If you really want to add a filter, you can add a `select` (for exemple) that you will write by using the hook `restrict_manage_posts`

```
<?php 
function display_select_filter() {
    global $post_type;
    if ($post_type == 'my-custom-post-type') { // must change post_type to yours
        $taxonomy = 'custom-tax'; // must change taxonomy to yours
        $terms = get_terms(['taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'hide_empty' => false]);
        ?>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="<?= $taxonomy; ?>_filter"><?= esc_html__("Category", 'my-domain'); ?></label>
        <select name="<?= $taxonomy; ?>" id="<?= $taxonomy; ?>_filter">
            <option value=""><?php _e("All categories", 'my-domain'); ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($terms as $k => $v): ?>
                <?php $selected = (!empty($_GET[$taxonomy]) && $_GET[$taxonomy] === $v->slug) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>
                <option value="<?= $v->slug; ?>"<?= $selected; ?>><?= $v->name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'display_select_filter');
```

To work properly; you have to replace `my-custom-post-type` with the slug of your post_type and `custom-tax` by the name of your taxonomy.

Comment: thanks for your reply I added this into my function.php but not work @pierre

Comment: But you helped me to understand what for I must search. I used this tutorial and worked. https://generatewp.com/filtering-posts-by-taxonomies-in-the-dashboard/ thank for everything

Comment: Thank you ! Normally, this code should work but it's true I didn't mention that you must replace with the name of your post_type and the name of your taxonomy (lines 3 & 4). I'll edit my message if it can help anybody ^^